# vb.net how to clone listview item and add row with timestamp

Tags: vb.net

I have a code that clones the listview item to the new listview (LSVCopyAdd), I want to add a timestamp to the item that was cloned in additional Column added for the time stamp (.Subitems(16)).

```
For i As Integer = LsvRead1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        item1 = LsvRead1.Items(i)
        For j As Integer = LsvCopyRemove.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            item2 = LsvCopyRemove.Items(j)
            If item1.SubItems(1).Text = item2.SubItems(15).Text AndAlso
                item1.SubItems(2).Text = LblGroup.Text Then
                LsvCopyAdd.Items.Add(DirectCast(item2.Clone, ListViewItem))
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
```

Any suggetions would be appriciated.

Comment: How do you usually add a subitem to an item? Why would this be any different? You'll need to change the structure of the code slightly but, if you understand what the code's doing, that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make this part of your code look like:

```
If item1.SubItems(1).Text = item2.SubItems(15).Text AndAlso
    item1.SubItems(2).Text = LblGroup.Text Then
    
    Dim newListViewItem As ListViewItem = DirectCast(item2.Clone, ListViewItem)
    newListViewItem.SubItems(16).Text = "your time stamp value"
    LsvCopyAdd.Items.Add(newListViewItem)
End If
```